# How should i start using entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am actually now using the typical `SqlDataReader` to fetch my data with visual studio 2005 but I want to start using the entity-framework. Are there any programs or backs I should download or install to do so?

Besides that, if i want to continue using my way is that a good idea?

thanxx

Comment: What is your current way? What are the problems you are encountering that suggest you should change? By "typical `SqlDataReader`" do you mean you are [ugh] embedding raw SQL, or are you already abstracting to stored procedures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vs2005 you can't but If you have VS2008 you could download [VS 2008 Service pack](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en) to work with EF, and if you have VS2010, It will be installed by default.

After installing it See **[Code First](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/23/entity-framework-4-code-first-custom-database-schema-mapping.aspx)**, there are lot of a resources with code first.
Also for startup is good too see [google search](http://innocraft.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!919A8CAC315ADF82!174.entry) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399567.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The entity framework I believe requires .net framework 3.5. 
There were some CTPs for VS2005 you might be able to get a hold of.
Otherwise I think VS2008 or VS2010 would be your best bet.

Here is a nice introduction for VS2008
[link text](http://zeetalks.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/vs2008-using-the-entity-framework/)

Answer (score 1):

I think everything you need is built into Visual Studio (though you'll probably want a newer version). Use Google to find a tutorial like [this one](http://naspinski.net/post/Getting-started-with-Linq-To-Entities.aspx), which will show you how to create and use an entity context based on your current SQL schema, and you should be on your way!

The Entity Framework takes a little getting used to (you have to remember that execution of LINQ queries is deferred!), but I've been using it for a couple of years now and it's hugely better than old-style data access methods. I definitely recommend it.